Why are random .wasm file requests failing on first load?
When loading our site after clearing cache, or in incognito mode, random .wasm files will fail to download, causing the site to be stuck on our loading screen. After refreshing it works correctly.
The errors in the browser console:
[2024-11-14T07:41:41.840Z] Warning: Initializer 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_content/FlexyBox.Core.Blazor/FlexyBox.Core.Blazor.lib.module.js' will be ignored because multiple runtimes are available. use 'before(web|webAssembly|server)Start' and 'after(web|webAssembly|server)Started?' instead.)
log @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
importInitializersAsync @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       GET https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm net::ERR_FAILED
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 Error in mono_download_assets: Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
Rr @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.catch
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.A [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4508)
    at dotnet.js:3:11593
    at dotnet.js:3:11609
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.then
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
4dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:9983
    at async K (dotnet.js:3:8871)
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8196)
    at async dotnet.js:3:7159
    at async Promise.all (index 184)
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.catch
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:9983
    at async K (dotnet.js:3:8871)
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8196)
    at async dotnet.js:3:7159
    at async Promise.all (index 184)
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
blazor.web.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ei (blazor.web.js:1:164030)
ei @ blazor.web.js:1
await in ei
Zr @ blazor.web.js:1
startWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:9983
    at async K (dotnet.js:3:8871)
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8196)
    at async dotnet.js:3:7159
    at async Promise.all (index 184)
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.runtime.8.0.10.92aq6ohvf8.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: download 'https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm' for System.Threading.wasm failed 0 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at dotnet.js:3:9983
    at async K (dotnet.js:3:8871)
    at async Y (dotnet.js:3:8196)
    at async dotnet.js:3:7159
    at async Promise.all (index 184)
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Ml.e.preRun @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.10.92aq6ohvf8.js:3
callRuntimeCallbacks @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
preRun @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
run @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
runCaller @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
removeRunDependency @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
(anonymous) @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.10.92aq6ohvf8.js:3
await in (anonymous)
(anonymous) @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.10.92aq6ohvf8.js:3
Ml.e.instantiateWasm @ dotnet.runtime.8.0.10.92aq6ohvf8.js:3
createWasm @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
(anonymous) @ dotnet.native.8.0.10.b3io2tkt2k.js:8
Fe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Fe
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Threading.wasm".
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       GET https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/FlexyBox.Core.Administration.MyWellness.wasm net::ERR_FAILED
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       GET https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Text.RegularExpressions.wasm net::ERR_FAILED
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       GET https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Text.Json.wasm net::ERR_FAILED
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.A [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4508)
    at dotnet.js:3:11593
    at dotnet.js:3:11609
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.then
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.A [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4508)
    at dotnet.js:3:11593
    at dotnet.js:3:11609
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.then
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 
        
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.A [as fetch_like] (dotnet.js:3:4508)
    at dotnet.js:3:11593
    at dotnet.js:3:11609
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
Promise.then
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/FlexyBox.Core.Administration.MyWellness.wasm".
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Text.RegularExpressions.wasm".
A @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
ne @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
K @ dotnet.js:3
Y @ dotnet.js:3
t @ dotnet.js:3
Z @ dotnet.js:3
await in Z
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
setTimeout
(anonymous) @ dotnet.js:3
await in (anonymous)
Pe @ dotnet.js:3
await in Pe
create @ dotnet.js:3
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
load @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
await in (anonymous)
ti @ blazor.web.js:1
startLoadingWebAssemblyIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
registerComponent @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
Ji @ blazor.web.js:1
dotnet.js:3 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://admin.flexybox.com/app/_framework/System.Text.Json.wasm".

The failed requests in the browser console's network tab
Some things we have tried:

We tried searching, but haven't been able to find anything.

We tried on different computers, and it still fails.

We tried another of our blazor sites, and it also fails there.

We tried in both firefox and chrome, it works in firefox, but not in chrome.

We tried running the following javascript in both chrome and firefox, that fetches one of the .wasm files with a random query parameter 250 times, and yesterday it seemed to cause the same error in both, but i can't reproduce it in firefox now.
document.testMethod = async () => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
        promises.push(fetch('https://azure.flexybox.com/blazor/_framework/System.Threading.Tasks.wasm?random=' + i.toString())
            .then(result => console.log(result)));
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
}
await document.testMethod();




Is this Net9 by any chance?

@MrC No, we are using .net 8
